# If pure caffeine is taken intravenously, will high dose cause nausea like it does when taken orally?

Tags: caffeine, symptoms, overdose

There are various symptoms of high caffeine intake. Among them, gastrointestinal symptoms are nausea, vomiting, diarrhea, abdominal pain, hyperactive bowel sounds etc. My question is: do these symptoms appear only in case of oral ingestion or in case of IV route too? You could describe generically i.e. other cases where gastrointestinal symptoms - which occur via oral route - may or may not occur via IV route. Thanks!

caffeine

Comment: Where do you think nausea arises from?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. Please improve your question with the help of prior comments and [ask].

Comment: How much caffeine are you taking ? I take 500 mg with no side affects.